# Why 'int16_t complex' does not work?

Tags: c, gcc, c99, complex-numbers, c11

Why `int16_t complex` does not compile while `int16_t` on a x86 and x86_64 machine, is a typedef on `short int`? Following is a sample code tested with gcc 5.4 and 4.9 with both C99 and C11 standards. Compiler complains about having two or more data types in declaration specifiers.

**Code:**

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float complex x = I + I / 3 * I / 2;
    short int complex y = I + I / 3 * I / 2;
    int16_t complex z = I + I / 3 * I / 2;       /* Why ? */
    printf("x=(%+f,%+f)\n", creal(x), cimag(x));
    printf("y=(%+f,%+f)\n", creal(y), cimag(y));
    printf("z=(%+f,%+f)\n", creal(z), cimag(z));  /* Why ? */
    return 0;
}
```

**Error:**

```
In file included from ./complex.c:1:0:
./complex.c: In function ‘main’:
./complex.c:9:13: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
     int16_t complex z = I + I / 3 * I / 2;       /* Why ? */
```

**Compiler command-line:**

```
gcc-5 --std=c99 ./complex.c -o ./complex
gcc-4.9 --std=c99 ./complex.c -o ./complex
```

Comment: Are you sure `short int complex` is accepted when running in C99 mode (`-std=c99`)? Consider pumping up the warning level.

Comment: @alk Yes. Even with `--pedantic` and `-Wall -Werror`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, complex integer types are a GCC extension. The C standard says ([C11 6.2.5p11](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p11)):

> 11 There are **three complex types**, designated as `float _Complex`, `double _Complex`, and `long double _Complex` .43) (Complex types are a conditional feature that implementations need not support; see 6.10.8.3.) The real floating and complex types are collectively called the floating types.

The `_Complex` is part of the type name, just like `long`. You cannot do this either:

```
typedef double dbl;
typedef long dbl ldbl;
```

i.e. to try to define a `typedef` for `ldbl` for `long double` when using a typedef for double! Likewise, you cannot use a `typedef` (such as `int16_t` is) when defining a complex type, use `short int _Complex` instead.

(And this of course applies to `complex` as well, as it is just a macro that expands to `_Complex`).

Answer (score 4):

This is because `_Complex` is part of a type name itself, not a modifier that can be used with other types. It does not work with typedefs of any kind, not only `short`. For example, if you do this

```
typedef float fp32;
fp32 _Complex x = I + I / 3 * I / 2;
```

you are going to see the same compile error.

Comment: That is interesting. Was this concept of spaced keywords inspired by C++/CLI?

Comment: @IllidanS4 ever heard of `unsigned char`... this is **C**.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala But `unsigned` is a keyword, isn't it? It is stated to be a modifier in many places.

Comment: @IllidanS4 [`_Complex` is a keyword too](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#A.1.2).

Answer (score 3):

Simply because there's no such type as `int16_t complex`. The valid complex types in C11 are `float complex`, `double complex`, and `long double complex`.

`complex` is a macro [which expands to `_Complex`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.3.1p4) which is the actual type specifier.

Comment: So why then `short int complex` and `int complex` work?

Comment: GCC supports [complex integer types](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Complex.html) as an extension, they are nonstandard.